# Android Studio: Releasing signed Bundle with native c++ Code just runs forever

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

I have an Android app that I want to release. I recently added a native c++ library and testing on the device worked fine. However, when I want to make a new release, I run into the following problem:
Generating Signed Bundle will just run forever without any error messages. This is the console output:

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build native-lib_armeabi-v7a
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/haenles/Development/private/myapp/app/.cxx/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a'

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
Build native-lib_arm64-v8a
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/haenles/Development/private/myapp/app/.cxx/cmake/release/arm64-v8a'
```

This is a screenshot of the "ongoing" Build:
[image]

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 23
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "de", "pt"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

The CmakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Screensot of my project setup:

[image]

I am using the latest Android Studio version, the latest gradle-wrapper and gradle version. I have already tried "Invalidate Caches and restart" and "Refresh linked c++ Projects". I am running Android Studio on Mac Os Catalina.
Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong here? This occurs only when I want to release a signed bundle. Building to a device just works fine.

To me it looks like the ninja is not able to build the arm64-v8a for some reason. Do I need additional configuration maybe?

Cheers,
Sym

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my c++ library into a c library and use make. No idea what the problem was, but now it works.